# WPF dragdrop control cursor escapes the control

Tags: c#, wpf

I've created my own dragable control. The dragging is very simple:

```
    bool moving = false; Point click = new Point(0, 0);

private void _MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    moving = true;
    click = Mouse.GetPosition(this);
}
private void _MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) { moving = false; }
private void _MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (moving == true)
    {
        Point po = Mouse.GetPosition(this);
        this.Margin = new Thickness(this.Margin.Left + (po.X - click.X), this.Margin.Top + (po.Y - click.Y), 0, 0);
    }
}
```

My problem is that if I drag too fast the cursor "escapes" my control. It's obvious why, however it's not too obvious how to fix this since I can't easily subscribe to every other control's mousemove in the window, and my control is small (about 35,15 px) so this happends a lot. I think that if I can easily force the mouse cursor to stay in the controll that would be a solution(not ideal, though). 
So what is the bast way to fix this? How professinoal controls handle this?

P.S. I'm learning WPF, so I'm probably doing some things wrong

Answer (score 0):

Your cursor leaves the usercontrol on fast moves and the MouseMove event will not be triggered anymore.

As said in the comments from the author in [Drag Drop UserControls](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/442276/Drag-and-Drop-WPF-Controls) using the MouseMove event of a surrounding Canvas should help.

Comment: Yeah, I know this, in winforms I would subscribe to .Parent 's mousemove, and it will work, but due to WPF nature it's not sure if that parent is bigger than the control itself..

Answer (score 0):

I've figured it out, it's very simple, using a timer.

```
    bool moving = false; Point click = new Point(0, 0); 
System.Timers.Timer _MOVER = new System.Timers.Timer();

public PersonControl() 
{
    InitializeComponent();



    _MOVER.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler((o, v) => { Dispatcher.Invoke(Move); });
    _MOVER.Enabled = true;
    _MOVER.Interval = 10;
}

private void _MouseDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    moving = true;
    click = Mouse.GetPosition(this);
    Canvas.SetZIndex(this, 100);
    _MOVER.Start();
}
private void _MouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) 
{ 
    moving = false;
    Canvas.SetZIndex(this, 0);
    _MOVER.Stop();
}
private void Move()
{
    if (moving == true)
    {
        Point po = Mouse.GetPosition(this);
        this.Margin = new Thickness(this.Margin.Left + (po.X - click.X), this.Margin.Top + (po.Y - click.Y), 0, 0);
    }
}
```